# When is OrderBy operator called?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

1)
a)

```
    var result1 = from artist in artists
                  from album in artist.Albums
                  orderby album.Title,artist.Name
                  select new { Artist_id = artist.id, Album_id = album.id };
```

Is the above query translated into:

```
        var result = artists.SelectMany(p => p.albums
            .Select(p1 => new { Artist = p, Album = p1 }))
            .OrderBy(p2 => p2.Album.Title)
            .ThenBy(p3 => p3.Artist.Name)
            .Select(p4 => new { Artist_id = p4.Artist.id, Album_id = p4.Album.id });
```

b) 
I'm not sure if this question will make much sense - If my assumptions are correct and thus `OrderBy` is always one of the last operators to get called ( when using query expression ), then how would we express the following code using query expression (in other words, how do we specify in a query expression that we want `OrderBy` operator to get called sooner and not as one of the last operators ):

```
        var result = artists
            .SelectMany(p1 => p1.albums
                .OrderBy(p2=>p2.title)
                .Select(p3 => new { ID = p3.id, Title = p3.title }));
```

2) Do in the following query expression the two `orderby` clauses get translated into `OrderBy(... artist.Name).OrderBy( ... album.Title)`:

```
        var result1 = from artist in artists
                      from album in artist.Albums
                      orderby artist.Name
                      orderby album.Title
                      select new { ...};
```

thank you

Comment: [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is great for this kind of questions.

Comment: I checked Linqpad at it seems it translates query expression directly into IL code ( which I can't read ), but it doesn't translate it into C# operator calls

Comment: Did you check the λ tab? Gives you a translation from query syntax to chained methods. Would help with 1a and 2, not 1b though. But I see Skeetpad already kicked in, forget Linqpad ;).

Comment: "Did you check the λ tab?" I did  click it and nothing happens ... just my luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1: `orderby` gets called wherever you show it. Your query isn't quite equivalent to what you showed, but it's close. It doesn't help that you formatted it so that it *looks* like the `Select` is called on the *result* of SelectMany, when it's actually on the *arguments* to SelectMany. Your query is translated to something more like:

```
var result = artists
    .SelectMany(artist => artist.albums, (artist, album) => new {artist, album})
    .OrderBy(z => z.album.Title)
    .ThenBy(z => z.artist.Name)
    .Select(z => new { Artist_id = z.artist.id, Album_id = z.album.id }
```

Question 1b) Your query is roughly equivalent to:

```
var result = from p1 in artists
             from p3 in (from p2 in p1.albums
                         orderby p2.title
                         new { ID = p2.id, Title = p2.title }) 
             select p3;
```

It's only a rough translation as nothing in query expressions is converted to that overload of `SelectMany`, as far as I can remember. On the other hand, it could be that this does what you want in a slightly simpler way:

```
var result = from p1 in artists
             from p3 in p1.albums.OrderBy(p2 => p2.title)
             select new { ID = p3.id, Title = p3.title };
```

You'll still get the ordering within the artist. It's a mixture of query expression and "dot notation", but it looks good to me. Odd that you're not using p1 in the final result, mind you...

For question 2, using two `orderby` clauses you do indeed get two `OrderBy` calls, which is almost certainly *not* what you want. You want:

```
var result1 = from artist in artists
              from album in artist.Albums
              orderby artist.Name, album.Title
              select new { ...};
```

That gets translated into the appropriate `OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)` calls.

Comment: 1 - Am I correct under 1a) and thus that query expression does get translated into code "artists.SelectMany(p => p.albums..." ? 2 - "So your query is roughly equivalent to:" uhm, if you're reffering to 1a) then I think you're mistaken

Comment: @user702769: There's certainly a call to artists.SelectMany, yes. My query is equivalent to your question 1b. Will answer your question 1a now. For future reference, it's a lot simpler if you stick to one question per post...

Comment: sorry for dragging this: As for 1a), I wasn't aware that particular SelectMany overload exists. Anyways, my code "artists.SelectMany(p => p.albums..."  gives the same result as query expression. Just a fluke or are they semantically equivalent ( even though query gets translated into different operator calls )?

Comment: @user702769: I can't immediately think of any semantic difference between the two...

Comment: I'm going to assume you're saying they are most likely semantically equivalent. Thank you for your help

Comment: @user702769: Yes - I *think* they're equivalent, but don't hold me to it :)